# Background image scaling to actual width but save propotions

Tags: html, css, background, resize, background-image

Im totaly newbie in html css and I discover it so annoying to write what I want to achieve... Not so easy language.
Generally I want to achieve effect like the first image with palms there - [https://spacebox.io/](http://spacebox.io)

but the thing is achieve is that [my www.rar file](http://www.speedyshare.com/jMA7E/www.rar)

I have no idea how to fix it.. its scales wrong and I can't achieve result like on spacebox.io

```
#topka{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 56px;
    margin: auto;
    height:350px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-image: url("img/topka.png");
    background-position: center; 
    background-size:100% 1200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:100%;
```

Comment: please put your code here and make a example here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i usually do this is wrap all my content within a div and style that div to fit the screen and place all content within it, for example:

HTML

```
<div id="background-cover">

    <!-- All page layout/divs/content here -->

</div>
```

And then target that element in css with this code, where background.jpg is your filename. You can use center center for perfect centered image:

```
#background-cover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `background-size: cover;` works in all modern browsers.